# perl code to declare array with the help of a loop

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to declare arrays while running of my loop. and I am stuck with it. I have no idea how to do it
When my program enters in for loop i want it to declare an array by itself and store the particular value in it. for ex :

```
    #!/bin/usr/perl -w 

    use strict;

    open(R1,"$file") || die ("error");

    while (my $line=<R1>) {
                        my $m=0;
                        for ( my $i=0 ; $i < my $l ; $i++ ){
              ##here i want to declare an array.  
              Such that each array stores each line from the file.

      }
```

input :
file1.txt

```
1      3  
4      6  
5      10  
3      5
```

output :

```
array 1: 1 3  
array 2: 4 6  
array 3: 5 1  
array 4: 3 5
```

i want to store each line from the file within a new array each time because i will use these arrays later in the program. the program should declare each array every time.

Comment: This is not actual script. How does file looks like and what is desired outcome?

Comment: i hope i have made you understand the logic of the programm

Answer (score 2):

I think that you don't really want to declare an array for every line of your input file. If you want to have your data available for further processing, you can read it simply into an array of arrayrefs. Here is some sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'file1.txt';
open( R1, "$file" ) or die "error reading $file: $!";

my @result;    # this array will hold referenced to the individual lines
while ( my $line = <R1> ) {
    chomp $line;    # get rid of trailing newline
    my @fields = split m/\s+/, $line;
    push @result, \@fields;
}
close R1;

print Dumper( \@result );    # show the data structure

# print the desired output
my $linenum = 1;
for my $array_ref (@result) {
    print "array $linenum: ", join( ' ', @{$array_ref} ), "\n";
    $linenum++;
}
```

For these sort of task you might also want to look at CPAN modules like [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm)

Comment: this is not helping for futher processing can you plz tell how i can declare array if their is a way

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking about is creating arrays dynamically based on user input (or in your case say number of lines). Mark Dominus, author of the enlightening book Higher-Order Perl, has explained pitfalls in detail, check the references.

References:

1. http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html
2. http://perl.plover.com/varvarname2.html
3. http://perl.plover.com/varvarname3.html
4. [Creating arrays dynamically in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545184/creating-arrays-dynamically-in-perl)